# How do I put the file tree at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: atom-editor

I really like Atom Editor, but since I use a lot of PDF documents to help me learn new programming languages, I split the screen down the middle so I have Atom on one side, and my PDF on the other. The problem is that I have to hide the file tree, since  it's used as a sidebar to access files, and if I have both my code and my file view on one half of the screen, it becomes difficult to read the code with it only taking up 25% of my screen. I was wondering if there was a way to put the file tree on the bottom of the screen? It might sound odd but for my use case it's what I need. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying it but it doesn't seem like it's possible to move the `tree-view` pane with drag-and-drop, and I don't see any settings related to moving it. :( Maybe there are other packages that could do it?

Comment: @wjandrea I've looked for packages; I can't seem to find any :(

Comment: If it helps, you can use the keyboard shortcut to show/hide the file tree. By default it's ctrl-\ or cmd-\.

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks for the info. Still, it's pretty disappointing that Atom can't implement this. It's as easy as drag-and-drop.

Comment: Atom is essentially a browser and through its user stylesheet, you can manipulate the layout pretty much as you want it to be. Personally, I don't see much sense in positioning an element providing a vertical list in a horizontal layout – it makes little to no sense (unless you rotate it by 90°…). My guess is the Atom team shares this opinion, hence there is no such option.